# R Extract Data From SurvFit

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival

```
library(survival)
etime <- with(mgus2, ifelse(pstat==0, futime, ptime))
event <- with(mgus2, ifelse(pstat==0, 2*death, 1))
event <- factor(event, 0:2, labels=c("censor", "pcm", "death"))

mfit2 <- survfit(Surv(etime, event) ~ sex, data=mgus2)

plot(mfit2, col=c(1,2,1,2), lty=c(2,2,1,1),
     mark.time=FALSE, lwd=2, xscale=12,
     xlab="Years post diagnosis", ylab="Probability in State")
legend(240, .6, c("death:female", "death:male", "pcm:female", "pcm:male"),
         col=c(1,2,1,2), lty=c(1,1,2,2), lwd=2, bty='n')
```

This is a reproducible example here. I wonder, how can it be possible to take out these data from  'mfit2' so it can be plotted in ggplot2?

Comment: What's wrong with that? Looks nicely.

Comment: str(mfit2), mfit2  is a list.. mfit2 [[1]] will give you  element one of the list

Comment: t<-bind_cols(time=mfit2$time, p=mfit2$pstate[,1] )
ggplot(data=t, aes(x=time, y=p)) + geom_point()

Comment: @jay.sf thanks so much it is so I can get confidence intervals on the figure. Do you have thoughts?

Comment: @Dr. Flow thanks so much, I wonder how it can be possible to extract surv probability and cumhaz for the three different groups (censor, pcm, death) ?

Comment: This isn't getting the time right, so far -- at least it's not 0-35 years, `df <- data.frame("time" = mfit2$time, "pcm" = mfit2$pstate[2], 
                   "death" = mfit2$pstate[3], 
                   "sex" = c(rep("male", 227), rep("female", 227)))
  df <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = 2:3, 
                            names_to = "state",
                            values_to = "prob")` (Needs `library(tidyr)`)

Comment: @bvowe I'm not sure, you might look into `?survival::plot.survfit`.

Comment: the `survminer` package provides a ggplot2 plotting of survival objects.

Comment: @emilliman5. Please provide an answer of how to do that with only `mfit2` and not the data, `mgus2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the data from the summary of the fitted object using `lapply`

```
sfit <- summary(mfit2)
str(sfit)

List of 24
 $ n            : int [1:2] 631 753
 $ time         : num [1:359] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ n.risk       : int [1:359, 1:3] 631 610 599 595 588 587 581 580 573 569 ...
 $ n.event      : int [1:359, 1:3] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ n.censor     : num [1:359] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ pstate       : num [1:359, 1:3] 0.968 0.951 0.944 0.933 0.932 ...
 $ p0           : num [1:2, 1:3] 1 1 0 0 0 0
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "sex=F" "sex=M"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "(s0)" "pcm" "death"
 $ strata       : Factor w/ 2 levels "sex=F","sex=M": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
...
```

I think the columns you need are the `time`, `pstate` and `strata. But some others, such as the numbers at risk may be useful.

```
cols <- lapply(c(2:6, 8, 16, 17), function(x) sfit[x])
```

Then combine these columns into a data frame with `do.call`

```
data <- do.call(data.frame, cols)
str(data)
'data.frame':   359 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ time     : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ n.risk.1 : int  631 610 599 595 588 587 581 580 573 569 ...
 $ n.risk.2 : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ n.risk.3 : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ n.event.1: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ n.event.2: int  0 2 0 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 ...
 $ n.event.3: int  20 9 4 6 1 5 1 7 2 2 ...
 $ n.censor : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ pstate.1 : num  0.968 0.951 0.944 0.933 0.932 ...
 $ pstate.2 : num  0 0.00317 0.00317 0.00476 0.00476 ...
 $ pstate.3 : num  0.0317 0.046 0.0523 0.0619 0.0634 ...
 $ strata   : Factor w/ 2 levels "sex=F","sex=M": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ lower.1  : num  0.955 0.934 0.927 0.914 0.912 ...
 $ lower.2  : num  NA 0.000796 0.000796 0.00154 0.00154 ...
 $ lower.3  : num  0.0206 0.0322 0.0375 0.0456 0.047 ...
 $ upper.1  : num  0.982 0.968 0.963 0.953 0.952 ...
 $ upper.2  : num  NA 0.0127 0.0127 0.0147 0.0147 ...
 $ upper.3  : num  0.0488 0.0656 0.0729 0.0838 0.0856 ...
```

This data is in wide format, best to reshape to long for the graph.

```
mgus3 <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=-c(time, strata, n.censor),
               names_to=c(".value","state"),
               names_pattern="(.+).(.+)") %>%
  filter(state!=1) %>%  # Exclude the censored state
  mutate(state=factor(state, labels=c("pcm","death")), 
         group=interaction(strata, state))
```

Then plot it.

```
library(ggplot)

mgus3 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=time, y=pstate, col=group)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=group)) +
  ylab("Probability in State") +
  theme_bw()
```

---

[image]

You should be able to add confidence bands and make it more pretty.

Comment: thank you so much, as another question I am wondering, where is it possible to extract the cumhaz data?

Comment: They are also in the `sfit` object - at position 12. You can extract these too.